# Adding metadata attributes to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, reflection, metadata

I would like to add custom attributes to a MySQL table which I can read via php.

These attributes are not to interfere with the table itself - they are primarily accessed by php code during code generation time and these attributes HAVE to reside in the DB itself.

Something similar in concept to .NET reflection.

Does MySQL support anything like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `CREATE` or `ALTER` a table, you can add `COMMENTS` - one for the table as a whole and one for each column. To retrieve these comments, you can query the database `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, specifically the columns `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMNS_COMMENT` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE.TABLE_COMMENTS`. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` provides a lot of metadata about your databases, including the data provided by `DESCRIBE` statements. Any user who has read access to a certain table or column can read the respective metadata from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but cannot read metadata about tables they do not have read access for.

It looks natural to store your custom metadata in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but it is not as flexible as you might need it because you can store only one `COMMENT` per column. If this is to restrictive for your purpose or you need to update the data regularly, you should follow @Dark Falcon and create an additional table.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from [titanoboa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468978/1617737), here's how to set a table's **COMMENT** value in PHP:

```
$my_comment = "Test comment.";
$mysqli->query("ALTER TABLE `my_table_name` COMMENT = '$my_comment'");
```

And here's how to read it back:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT `TABLE_COMMENT` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'my_db_name' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'my_table_name' LIMIT 1");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
$my_comment = $row['TABLE_COMMENT']; // "Test comment."
```

Answer (score 1):

What kind of attributes? Since you mention reflection, I assume you're trying to find something out about the table structure? Did you realize that the commands that tell you about the table structure are SQL and return their results as any other query? This lets you progammatically process the results of, for example, DESCRIBE TABLE. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I want to add my own information to the list that DESCRIBE TABLE returns.  My own CUSTOM attributes.

Comment: Long and short of it is pretty much: "You can't". Keep a separate table with columns for table_name, field_name, attribute_name, etc.